# Shows missing field item in breadcrumb schema

Tags: wordpress, plugins, schema.org, yoast

Google search console shows the following issue while inspecting all the url of the website.

missing field “position”

either “name” or “item.name”should be specified

As per the recommendation for another similar request, I installed a health check and troubleshooting plugin. But there was no issue related to this. The recommended improvements were to remove inactive plugins and themes. There are no other on-page issues on our website and our ranking is not improving due to this issue. Why this issue occurs and how to remove this issue manually. I enabled Yoast seo breadcrumb but it affects the site design also. How yoast seo add this breadcrumb schema on the website?

I installed health check and troubleshooting plugin. But there was no error regarding this. The yoast seo community says, they only create JSON LD and the schema related to this issue is in microdata. They recommended to communicate with Theme developer.